# Solve $\frac{1}{|x-2|} > 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I tried this:
\begin{align*}
            \frac{1}{|x-2|} > 1
            &\iff \left|\frac{1}{x-2}\right| > 1\\
            &\iff \frac{1}{x-2} > 1 \vee \frac{1}{x-2} < -1\\
            &\iff 1 > x-2 \vee 1 < 2 - x\\
            &\iff 3 > x \vee 1>x
        \end{align*}
Which means that $x\in (-\infty, 3)\cup (-\infty, 1)$. But the solution should be $x\in\left(1,\:2\right)\cup \left(2,\:3\right)$.

Comment: Going from the first line to the second line, you have swept *a lot* of important information under the rug.  It might be a good idea to work out the details of that computation in more detail (perhaps, even, going back to the definition of $|\cdot|$).

Comment: When you multiply inequalities you should always ensure they're positive (otherwise the sign flips). I suggest that at the very first step, multiply by $|x-2|$ (which is a positive quantity if $x\neq 2$), and then simplify (this approach is much less likely to cause errors).

Comment: In any event, I think that this question is very similar to other questions which have been asked before, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754625/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083953/ .

Comment: Thanks. Multiplying by $|x-2|$ as @peek-a-boo said I got the result.